# What is the correct projection used in Basemap Matplotlib for AIRS in Aqua?

Tags: image-processing, matplotlib, gis

I want to plot the image taken from AIRS (Atmospheric Infrared Sounder) on a map by using Basemap Matplotlib. But I couldn't find the correct projection type for it. Does anybody know which projection should be used?

[AIRS info link](http://aqua.nasa.gov/about/instrument_airs.php)

like this one:

http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/AIRS/data-holdings/by-data-product/images/airsvbrad.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page ["How to choose a projection"](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm) by Jochen Albrecht has lots of practical rule of thumb (unlike many similar pages which tend to be trapped to the underlying math).  If you are interested in particular part of earth, look at sections "Which part of the world does your map show?", "What shape is your area of interest?" etc.

There is no "correct" projection, although there are good and bad projections for each particular purpose.

**EDIT**

The particular image you attached showing near the green land looks to me like a polar stereographic projection, taking 30degree west or so as central meridian.  So try with 'npstere' as projection, -30 for lon_0 (or 330 if it doesnt like negative number).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like [this](http://airs.jpl.nasa.gov/AIRS_CO2_Data/) then you want a Mollweide projection.  Or if you'd rather it be square like [this](http://climate.uvic.ca/climate-lab/front_page_pics/temperature.lrg.jpeg) then try a Mercator projection.  It really just depends on how much data you are looking at.  If this doesn't help, can you give an example of what you are looking for?